# add new data into existing file

Tags: shell-script

how do you include additional data into existing file?

Example File1 :

Apple 
Pear 
Orange

```
grep 'Pear' File1 >> File2

INdate=`date +'%m/%d/%Y'
```

File2 Output :
Pear  **12.14.2016**

How do i get the date to be inside File2? 
Any help will be appreciated.
 Thank you.

Comment: Sort out the formatting. The date produced by `date +'%m/%d/%Y'` will not look like `12.14.2016`. It is further unclear whether you want the date added to the end of a _particular_ line in `File2` (you start off by appending to the file, so it may not be empty), or just added to the end of the file. Your shell example with `grep` also includes a syntax error (missing backtick).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and sorry for the missing out the back tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for example `sed` to replace the end-of-line with the output of the `date` command:

```
grep 'Pear' File1 |
sed -e 's#\s*$# '"$(date +'%m/%d/%Y')"'#' >>File2
```

Comment: this works, thank you. I have another question, can I add two data to File2?

Comment: this works, thank you. I have another question, can I add two data to File2? Example, current date and date the goods will be delivered? I have the delivered date calculated but I don't know how to implement it together in the sed so that both date appear in File2.

Answer (score 2):

```
date +'%m/%d/%Y' >> File2
```